# WebClient DownloadString gives error when using Webproxy C#

Tags: c#, proxy, webclient, webproxy

Im trying to use WebClient.DownloadString() but using proxy.
Im doing this:

```
 WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://000.000.000.000:80"); (here goes real proxy ip)
        WebClient wb = new WebClient();
        wb.Proxy = wp;
        try
        {
            string file = wb.DownloadString("http://google.com/");
            System.Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

And it gives this error when DownloadString is call:

> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexion: Error inesperado de recepcion. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexion de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupcion de una conexion existente por el host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupcion de una conexion existente por el host remoto

If I don't use proxy, it works fine. The proxy also works fine, cause if I configure proxy in Chrome or Firefox, I can access any web page.

Thanks

Comment: Erm...No puedo hablar Español. Could you translate it into Americanese?

Comment: Would this make a good translation? System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 120.203.215.6:85

Comment: Don't forget to remove your IP from your comment.

Comment: Does your proxy have IP restrictions set up?

Comment: Translation is something like this:

Comment: System.Net.WebException: Conection finished: Unespected error in reception. ---> System.IO.IOException:cannt write dataen in transport conection: Forced interruption of existing connection by remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Force interruption of existing connection by remote host.

I have checked and it seems a proxy problem, im using an internet list of proxys, and if i check, some of them seems to work, and someones not. I really don't understand very well why...

Answer (score 0):

The error that was reported means that there was a RST (reset) packet sent to your computer. It could have been from the proxy or from some firewall that was in the way, but the message `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` means that something forcibly closed the connection (and in TCP that means a RST packet). My first guess is that the proxy address or port wasn't set correctly.

Comment: The proxy is correct, but it seems that some proxys doesn't support the request to some webs. They are free public hosts from internet lists.